# Conditional formatting pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting

How do I colour in cells below 1 as green and cells between 0 and 0.5 yellow for Column C.

Current output:

```
   A    B    C
0 TT    WW   -5
1 AA    WW   0
2 DD    WW   5
```

Desired:

[image]

The following code for me just writes to Excel with no colour change.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_excel("C:\\13\\13\\13.xlsx")
def highlight_vals(val, min=-1111, max=1, color='green'):
    if min < val < max:
        return 'background-color: %s' % color
    else:
        return ''
df.style.applymap(highlight_vals, subset=['C'])

def highlight_vals(val, min=0, max=0.5, color='yellow'):
    if min < val < max:
        return 'background-color: %s' % color
    else:
        return ''
df.style.applymap(highlight_vals, subset=['C'])


writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\13\\13\\zz.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer, startrow=0, startcol=0, index = False)

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_excel("C:\\13\\13\\13.xlsx")
def highlight_vals(val, min=-1111, max=1, color='green'):
    if min <= val <= max:
        return 'background-color: %s' % color
    else:
        return ''
style_1 = df.style.applymap(highlight_vals, subset=['C'])

def highlight_vals(val, min=0, max=0.5, color='yellow'):
    if min <= val <= max:
        return 'background-color: %s' % color
    else:
        return ''
style_2 = df.style.applymap(highlight_vals, subset=['C'])

style_1.use(style_2.export())

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\13\\13\\zz.xlsx")
style_1.to_excel(writer, startrow=0, startcol=0, index = False)

writer.save()
```

I kept both `Styler` objects, applied one on another and saved the resulting one to Excel instead of a dataframe. Also note that I fixed your conditions. Otherwise, you won't get yellow color because of `min < val`

Comment: My Excel does not change using this

Comment: Positive.I am using windows 10. Copied that code exactly.  Maybe its wrong approach.  The output appears but no colour change

Comment: How do you run the code? If you run from Jupyter, you can check results after every time you apply new style like `display(style_1)`. Each time you should see coloured tables

Comment: I am using pycharm.  Perhaps there is colour change if I had Jupyter.  Can this be written to excel though or in pandas you can only colour dataframes but change is not noticed in excel.  Is xlsxwriter required?

Comment: Everything works fine for me from PyCharm as well. I don't know about xlsxwriter, but I had to install `openpyxl`

Comment: Maybe its a windows bug as I am using that code but my output is same.  No green and yellow columns appear for me ha

Comment: what is your pandas version?

Comment: My pandas was a little out of date.  It's at 0.21.0 now though still same issue.

Comment: Try `style_1.to_excel(writer, startrow=0, startcol=0, index=False, engine='openpyxl')`

Comment: Also, you can specify `engine='xlsxwriter'`. Try both

Comment: Unfortunately no change